# Can I enable the Honeypot module for comments on the Advanced Forum pages?

Tags: advertising

How do I configure the Honeypot module to work on comment pages for the Advanced Forum module?

I enabled the Honeypot module, checked *Blog entry node form* and *Forum topic node form* in *Node forms* and *Comment forms*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module configuration page is just the one on /admin/config/content/honeypot, which has the following settings.

> [image: screenshot]

If you expect to see a difference on protected forms, there isn't anything visible. The module creates a form element that is hidden to users, but tools that automatically fill the form will fill also that, making clear they aren't human users.
The module also doesn't accept a form submission before *time limits* seconds are passed from the moment the form is rendered.

If you are testing a form using a user account with the *administrator* role, that has the *Bypass Honeypot protection* permission, so you will not see any hidden form element even watching at the HTML markup of the page.